# Substitute text using match in a non greedy way?

Tags: php, xml, regex, preg-match

I have a SOAP Call that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:FileserveAPI" xmlns:types="urn:FileserveAPI/encodedTypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><tns:login><username xsi:type="xsd:string">REPLACEME</username><password xsi:type="xsd:string">REPLACEMETOO</password></tns:login></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I want to replace REPLACEMEE and REPLACEMETOO with defined values, but in the subject those values can be anything.

I tried theese preg_match rules:

```
$body = preg_replace('#>.+?</username>#','>myuser</username>',$body);
$body = preg_replace('#>.+?</password>#','>mypw/username>',$body);
```

But I end up with this string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>myuser</username></tns:login></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I cant understand why?

Why is this occouring and how do I need to modify my rules?

Edit:

I already worked my way around it with a negated character class like `[^>]+` however I am still intersted in why the non greedyness doesnt work.

Comment: Are you aware that well-formed XML can contain spaces in the start and end tags? So you are placing constraints on the senders of these documents beyond the fact that they are valid XML? Processing XML without a proper XML parser is WRONG. It can also be very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "non greedyness" works as expected.

The first regex started when it encountered `>` and then took only the minimum until the first `</username>` was reached.

If the XML had been:

```
<?xml version="1.0"><accnt1><username>foo</username></accnt1><accnt2><username>bar</username></accnt2> ...
```

Then `>.+?</username>` grabs:

```
><accnt1><username>foo</username>
```

Whereas `>.+</username>` would grab:

```
><accnt1><username>foo</username></accnt1><accnt2><username>bar</username>
```

Comment: ok that makes sense! if i understand that correctly i could put y greedy match in front to compensate for that - in this case - undesired behaviour, right?

Comment: Yes, if you were careful.  Better to use the `[^>]+` type approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$body = preg_replace("/(<username[^>]+>).+?(<\/username>)/", "$1new value$2", $input);
$body = preg_replace("/(<password[^>]+>).+?(<\/password>)/", "$1new value..$2", $input);
```

Comment: thanks, i already had a quick fix using a negated character class [^>] but your works fine and looks good. i am still curious why the non greedyness doesnt work though